# replication or web service

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, web-services, replication

We are thinking through an integration between 3 disparate systems (owned by different companies) which need to coordinate data (one business owner of data). One of the options is to use web services to push data from system to system.  All the systems are on sql server, so replication of limited data is also a possibility.

Anyone who has tried both techniques care to comment on the pros/cons?  Each of the systems might be a master of a subset of data which is to be pushed into the others.  Specifically, i'm curious how failed transactions are handled in web services.

Answer (score 3):

We have a similar environment, where we are keeping 3 systems in sync (Access, business-owned SQL Azure, and 3rd-party SQL Azure).  We started with web service integration, but we're slowly moving to tighter SQL-to-SQL replication mostly for performance reasons.  Our implementation is completely custom (not using any built-in synchronization or replication services provided by SQL Server), basically using BulkImport and set-based queries to synchronize.

### Web Services

Pros

- Loosely coupled (if designed right), so better risk management if any piece changes or is swapped out.
- Better access control
- Better integration with existing applications built on the database.
- Highly scalable.

Cons

- Can be very slow for moving a large amount of data.
- Transactions and data processing must be handled manually - but can be done.

### SQL Integration

Pros

- Much higher throughput.
- Can be easier to manage if the table structures are relatively simple to map.
- Transactional support.

Cons

- Easy to make big mistakes, like wiping out whole tables, messing up entire columns, etc.
- Difficult to build solid error handling if you have to roll your own integration for set-based replication.
- Tight integration between the systems will be very hard if the structures of the tables are very different, i.e., one is EAV model like our system.

If I had my choice and performance wasn't a problem, I'd definitely choose web services.  The nature of our 3 systems is that they have vastly different table structures, so a web service that abstracts away the backend table structure into a simple POCO data structure being passed around keeps things a lot simpler.  Also, one of the 3 systems drives a website which exposes a web service that "just works" without worrying about cached records, simultaneous updates, etc.

The way we currently handle transactional updates with our web service integration goes something like this (server should be the side that is more complex and more likely to fail):

1. Client initiates a connection to server.
2. Client begins a local transaction.
3. Server begins a local transaction.
4. Server processes request.
5. Server commits/rolls back local transaction based on success/fail.
6. Server sends back response with success/fail and error message(s).
7. Client handles response.
8. Client commits/rolls back local transaction based on success/fail.